# Searching an ArrayList by multiple object attribute

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class `Person` with the first and the last name, and a class `Student` with grade averages and final grades, that inherits Person.

```
public class Student extends Person
{
    private double HomeworkAve;
    private double QuizAve;
    private double ProjectAve;
    private double TestAve;
    private double FinalGrade;
    private String LetterGrade;

    public Student(){}

    public Student(String FName, String LName, double HomeworkAve, double QuizAve, double ProjectAve, double TestAve) {

        super(FName, LName);

        this.HomeworkAve = HomeworkAve;
        this.QuizAve = QuizAve;
        this.ProjectAve = ProjectAve;
        this.TestAve = TestAve;
    }



    public void setHomeworkAve(double HomeworkAve) {
        this.HomeworkAve = HomeworkAve;
    }

    public void setQuizAve(double QuizAve) {
        this.QuizAve = QuizAve;
    }

    public void setProjectAve(double ProjectAve) {
        this.ProjectAve = ProjectAve;
    }

    public void setTestAve(double TestAve) {
        this.TestAve = TestAve;
    }
```

I want to be able to search for a student by name, so in my main class, I used this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < aloStudent.size(); i++) {
    String xsFirstName = aloStudent.get(i).getFName();

    if (xsFirstName.equals(xsFName) == true) 
    {
        System.out.println("found");
    }
}
```

While debugging, I noticed that `xsFirstName` has the correct value, but then when it goes to compare it to `xsFName` (which is the user's input) it skips the `println`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Its hard to tell from just the code above.  One thing to check is that the "user's input" (which I assume is xsFName) does not contain leading or trailing spaces. That would make the comparison fail. Try applying trim() to the input.  Also, the "==true" above is not necessary.

Comment: why are you doing `.equals(xsFName)` == true???? `.equals()` itself will give you either true or false for `if` condition. Also, have you checked using `if(xsFirstName.intern().equals(xsFName)){......}`...? Also, in your debugging, did you find out what the user input value was? Given your code snippet, it is quite difficult to tell what is going on unless you can report that the user input was different. You seem to be using the `.equals()` correctly....check the user input `xsFName`

Comment: If you don't want a case sensitive comparison you can use the String.equalsIgnoreCase() method or to convert both strings to upper/lower case and then use String.equals().

Comment: Adding the trim didn't work, and I took out the comparison. Yes, I saw the values held in the variables, and there were no extra spaces, and they both held the same string.

Comment: And you can't provide an example input and a sample `aloStudent` content, because ....? How should we be able to reproduce your problem without that?

Comment: Sorry, I've added the class. Like I said, I'm new at this, and I'm not sure what people need yet.

Comment: If you're new, then you should read this help page: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Can you please add the following: 1.: the code there you add `Student` instances to your `aloStudent` list. 2.: an example input for a searched first name that couldn't be found in your list.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the shorter version

```
if (aloStudent.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.getFName().equals(xsFName))) {
    System.println("found");
}
```

Comment: This answer assumes Java 8.